# Mozilla Persona/BrowserID email address and cookies

Tags: javascript, authentication, session-cookies, mozilla, browserid

Sorry for the generic title. I'm playing around with Mozilla's Persona at the moment. I'm using Express.js with the [express-persona](http://jbuck.github.com/express-persona/) middleware so setting everything up was incredibly simple. The client-side part is easy too, but I'm having a hard time understanding one particular part of the documentation. It says:

> *loggedInUser:* The email address of the user currently logged into your
>   site from this computer, or *null* if noone is logged in. **For example,
>   you might examine the browser's cookies to determine who is signed in.**
>   [...] Persona will compare the email address you've passed into
>   *loggedInUser* with its own knowledge of whether a user is currently
>   logged in, and who they are. If these don't match, it may
>   automatically invoke *onlogin* or *onlogout* on page load.
>   ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Quick_Setup#Step_3.3A_Watch_for_login_and_logout_actions))

express-persona sets a cookie which includes (I guess) the crypto-foo that acts as a password replacement. Am I supposed to store the email address returned by the backend in a separate cookie? That doesn't seem to be a very good idea.  Maybe one of you guys knows how that's supposed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't store the email address in a cookie for Persona, any more than you'd store the username in a cookie for a password-driven login.

No, basically you do the same thing with Persona: Use a session, stored on your server, keyed from a cookie. The only difference is that your site went through the Persona auth process, instead of verifying a username + password.

The example on the page you linked to has a currentUser variable. Well, in a real web site, that variable would be filled in as a template from the server side. Do whatever you would do to support a login session, find the currently authenticated user, insert that user's email address.

Comment: Thing is I'm not doing anything really. It looks like the express middleware does everything for me. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/YpF8WsfY) the example from the MDN page and [here's](http://pastebin.com/1kBrx6e8) the express-persona example. I click the button, sign in, close the tab, open a new tab, connect to localhost again and I'm signed in automatically. It feels like I'm supposed to set the *currentUser* variable before doing the ajax call though.

Comment: Yeah, [looks like express-persona does exactly what I suggested](https://github.com/jbuck/express-persona/blob/master/index.js#L71): It stores the verified email in the current session under a configurable key (`email`, by default). So, it looks like you'd get the current authenticated email from `request.session.email` and just count on express-persona to set that for you

Comment: Yup that's what I figured. I guess I just don't understand the purpose of the *currentUser* variable then. I can live with that. Thanks :)